# How do I set up Quixote with Karma?

Tags: css, karma-runner

[Quixote](https://github.com/jamesshore/quixote) looks really cool.  Am having a bit of trouble getting it working with Karma. I tried emulating [Bjorn's example](https://github.com/bjornicus/tddcss) but am getting this error:

```
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
```

In my karma.conf.js, I have:

```
files: [
    'www/latest/tests/lib/jasmine-beforeAll.js',
    'www/latest/tests/lib/sinon-1.7.3.js',
    'www/latest/tests/test-main.js',
    {pattern: 'www/latest/vendor/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'www/latest/app/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'www/latest/tests/lib/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'www/latest/tests/specs/**/*.js', included: false},
    'node_modules/quixote/dist/*.js'
],
```

Then in my test, I have

```
var quixote = require("../../../../node_modules/quixote/dist/quixote.js");
```

(this seems redundant as having Quixote in files hash would make it globally available but wanted to follow Bjorn's example to the letter).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plugin I made, please file tickets if it doesn't work for you.  https://github.com/woldie/karma-quixote

```
npm install --save-dev karma-quixote
```